# Django: How to import a javascript inside another javascript file

Tags: javascript, django

How to import inside JavaScript files and using **Django** to load another js.

Statements like these don't work:

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '{% static "@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js" %}';
import '{% static "@polymer/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.js" %}';
```

And also these too:

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '@polymer/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.js';
```

```js
// myapp-shell.js
import `${static_path}`;
//....
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        {% load static %}
        <script src="{% static 'node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js' %}"></script>

        <!-- Loading app-shell -->
        <script>
            var static_path = '{% static "my-icons.js" %}';
            console.log(static_path);
        </script>
        <script type="module" src="{% static 'mycomponents/myapp-shell.js' %}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <myapp-shell></myapp-shell>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there is a way to do that without bundling the code in one big file, nor calling all files may be needed in the html file.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely not right to use Django template tags inside your JS files, since they will not be processed by Django's template loader. I'd suggest either:

(a) Use only relative path imports in your JS files.

or

(b) Set up your Django `STATICFILE_DIRS` setting to include the node_modules directory and setting `STATIC_ROOT` to something like '/static'. Then do your module imports as `import { x } from '/static/path/to/module'`.

EDIT: Grammar

Answer (score 1):

I searched that for a long time and the way I found to do that is:

inside your mains script use this function.

```
function include(file) { 
  
    var script  = document.createElement('script'); 
    script.src  = file; 
    script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    script.defer = true; 
    
    document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(script); 
    
}
```

then load your script like this:

```
include('/static/js/your_js_file.js');
```

don't forget to register your static files directory in settings.py

example:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "your_folder of library"),
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Mabe you can use a global variable at top of your js importations, because static it's only for django template, you can do something like this inside your template file:

```
<script>
    var static_path = '{% static "@polymer/polymer/" %}';
</script>
```

end then import your js files using this path

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from `${static_path}/polymer-element.js" %}`;
```

Comment: sorry, but it causes a syntax error. I tried some variation of this method and it didn't work.

Comment: remember if you want import in a js file you must be set type to module so in your js file you want import mustbe declare like this <script type="module" src="your_path" ></script>

Comment: var static_path = '{% static "my-icons.js" %}';

import `${static_path}`;

myapp-shell.js:29 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected template string

Comment: import ${static_path} or import `${static_path}` ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180541/discussion-between-ahmad-abdelghany-and-root-kidz).

Comment: It's definitely not right to use Django template tags inside your JS files, since they will not be processed by Django's template loader. I'd suggest either (a) using only relative path imports in your JS file or (b) setting up your Django `STATICFILE_DIRS` setting to include the node_modules directory and setting `STATIC_ROOT` to something like '/static'. Then do your module imports as `import { x } from '/static/path/to/module'`

Comment: I used a relative path like @whusterj said. You can post it as an answer to accept it, or shall I post it.

Comment: Thanks, posted my comment as an answer!